# How to delete widgets from a cell in a QGridLayout

Tags: qt, qt4

I am not able to remove a particular widget from a cell in a qgridlayout. I tried several codes found in internet... but i failed!! the way how i did the work was, first i created a qwidget class containing button,qpixmap,qplaintextedit. i then created an object of this class and it was set dynamically on the QGridLayout. the layout was then set on the current widget using this pointer. I am able to addwidgets on the gridlayout, but not able to delete it.. i want to delete the whole widget i created only if the pixmap is null!!! Do anyone knows a suitable remedy for this problem??

Comment: Removing items from a layout which are contained within nested child layouts can be difficult. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19256990/1070129) for a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a widget without deleting it, call

```
void QLayout::removeWidget(QWidget*)
```

To remove and delete a widget, just delete it.