# Delete A Row From QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt

All, I am maintaining a `QGridLayout` of `QLabels` which show the coefficients of a polynomial.  I represent my polynomial using `QList<double>`.

Each time I update my coefficients, I update my labels.  When changing the size of the list, my method **does not** works well.  `QGridLayout::rowCount()` doesn't update correctly.  I am wondering if there's a way to remove rows from a QGridLayout.

---

Code follows, updating the `QGridLayout` size with more (or less) `QLabels`

```
int count = coefficients->count(); //coefficients is a QList<double> *
if(count != (m_informational->rowCount() - 1)) //m_information is a QGridLayout
{
    SetFitMethod(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        QLabel * new_coeff = new QLabel(this);
        new_coeff->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
        m_informational->addWidget(new_coeff, i+1, 0);
        QLabel * param = new QLabel(this);
        param->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
        param->setText(QString("<b><i>x</i><sup>%2</sup></b>").arg(count-i-1));
        m_informational->addWidget(param, i+1, 1);
        QSpacerItem * space = new QSpacerItem(0,0,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
        m_informational->addItem(space, i+1, 1);
    }

    m_informational->setColumnStretch(0, 3);
    m_informational->setColumnStretch(1, 1);
    m_informational->setColumnStretch(2, 1);
}
```

The SetFitMethod (it's an initial mockup)

```
void SetFitMethod(int method)
{
    ClearInformational();
    switch(method)
    {
    case 0: //Polynomial fit
        QLabel * title = new QLabel(this);
        title->setText("<b> <u> Coefficients </u> </b>");
        title->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
        m_informational->addWidget(title,0,0,1,3, Qt::AlignHCenter);
    }
}
```

The Clearing Method:

```
void ClearInformational()
{
    while(m_informational->count())
    {
        QLayoutItem * cur_item = m_informational->takeAt(0);
        if(cur_item->widget())
            delete cur_item->widget();
        delete cur_item;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing widgets from QGridLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395266/removing-widgets-from-qgridlayout)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that `QGridLayout::rowCount()` doesn't actually return the number of rows that you can see, it actually returns the number of rows that `QGridLayout` has internally allocated for rows of data (yes, this isn't very obvious and isn't documented).

To get around this you can either delete the `QGridLayout` and recreate it, or if you're convinced that your column count won't change, you can do something like this:

```
int rowCount = m_informational->count()/m_informational->columnCount();
```

Comment: Yep after some intense debugging, I figured that out as well...  I like your division solution, however it is very specific to my work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating a QVBoxLayout (for rows) and within this I was adding QHBoxLayout (for columns). In the QHBoxLayout I was then inserting my widgets (in one row). This way I was able to nicely remove rows - overall row count was working as it should be. Additionally to this I got also an insert method, thanks to which I was able to insert new rows into specific locations (everything was correctly reordered/renumbered).

Example (only from head):

```
QVBoxLayout *vBox= new QVBoxLayout(this);

//creating row 1
QHBoxLayout *row1 = new QHBoxLayout();
QPushButton *btn1x1 = new QPushButton("1x1");
QPushButton *btn1x2 = new QPushButton("1x2");
row1->addWidget(btn1x1);
row1->addWidget(btn1x2);
//adding to vBox - here you can use also insertLayout() for insert to specific location
vBox->addlayout(row1); 

//creating row 2
QHBoxLayout *row2 = new QHBoxLayout();
QPushButton *btn2x1 = new QPushButton("2x1");
QPushButton *btn2x2 = new QPushButton("2x2");
row2->addWidget(btn2x1);
row2->addWidget(btn2x2);
//adding to vBox - here you can use also insertLayout() for insert to specific location
vBox->addlayout(row2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, my solution was to also delete the `QGridLayout` in `ClearInformational`