# Remove Widget from QGridLayout in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a very basic doubt regarding `QGridLayout`.
For adding a widget in `QGridLayout` we give `QWidget *` that should be added along with the `row` & `column` no (some other args as well).
Now for removing a widget there is no function to *remove a widget according to row & column no* i.e. something like this:

```
int row, column;
gridObj->remove(row, column);
```

I think `QGridLayout` must be maintaining a sort of `QList` to store *references of Widgets & there positions*. So why is there no function for removing widgets by position only?
It only has 1 remove function for which we need to specify the reference of `QWidget` object.

If this is a limitation somehow then is there a workaround for this problem?
Maintaining a QList by myself is a solution but it is pretty tedious.
Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be mistaken here, but from skimming the documentation, try this:

1. Get the QLayoutItem at the position (**[QGridLayout::itemAtPosition](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#itemAtPosition)(row, column)**).
2. Use the QLayoutItem to get the widget pointer (**[QLayoutItem::widget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayoutitem.html#widget)()**).
3. Use the widget pointer to find the index of the widget in the QGridLayout (**[QLayout::indexOf](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#indexOf)(widgetPointer)**).
4. Use the index to take ownership of the widget from the layout (**[QGridLayout::takeAt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#takeAt)(index)**).
5. Wrap it all in a convenience function?

I've always had trouble reordering widgets in layouts, removing widgets from layouts, and etc... Oftentimes, I just resort to deleting the layout and re-adding the widgets. =(

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer, I will try that & get back to you.
Regarding the complexities of layouts in Qt, I also feel the same.
Sometimes I wonder why did they make this so ridiculously confusing to use.
But anyway rest of the Qt is pretty fine to understand...

Comment: In a grid layout, what is the no returned by QLayout::indexOf()?
Is it the row or column no, or is it simply some index of a list?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's a 1-dimension index into a list.

Answer (score 4):

For removing a widget within a QGridLayout by layout position, you can simply use

```
layout->removeWidget(layout->itemAtPosition(row, column)->widget());
```

However, you have to note the following about it:

- This code assumes that there actually is an item on the
  specified position in the layout. If it isn't, itemAtPosition() will
  return null. So you need to be sure about the position, or check it explicitly.
- This code will remove the widget from the layout, but not delete it. 
  You have to put the widget back into a different layout or give the
  widget a reasonable geometry yourself. If you don't, the widget will simply keep
  visible at its current position. If you want the widget to be
  destructed, you'll have to delete it explicitly after it has been
  removed from the layout.
- This code will only work for top-level widgets within the layout which have been
  added with `addWidget()`. It won't work for nested layouts added with `addLayout()`.
  If you need to care about nested layouts as well, see
  [my answer about removing rows and columns from grid layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19256990/1070129).